# Refresh Google Token using azure-mobile-apps with Cordova

Tags: cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services, google-signin

How do I refresh a Google Token using azure-mobile-apps with Cordova?

From what I understand I need to use ‘access_type=offline’ or '/.auth/refresh'. However, I’m not sure how to implement these. **Below is my attempt which returns 403 – Forbidden:**

```
//var url = AzureDbSvc.client.applicationUrl + '/.auth/me'; /* Note - This Works */
var url = AzureDbSvc.client.applicationUrl + '/.auth/refresh'; 

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('X-ZUMO-AUTH', AzureDbSvc.client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
fetch(url, { headers: headers })
.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.status + ' : ' + data.statusText); //<<-- 403 : Forbidden
    ...
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Chris! The below works but please let me know if you see any issues or if it can be improved upon...

```
// Initial google login
AzureDbSvc.client.loginWithOptions('google', { parameters: { access_type: 'offline' } })
    .then(function (token) {...});


// Refresh token request
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('X-ZUMO-AUTH',
   AzureDbSvc.client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);

fetch(url, { headers: headers })
    .then(function (data) {
       console.log(data.status + ' : ' + data.statusText); //<<== 200 : OK
       var user_json = data.json();
       console.log('user_json:' + user_json);
       return user_json;
}).then(function (refreshToken) {...});
```

Comment: I did get some type of a warning like, "**Embedded Google OAuth Refresh Token Developer**" warning when calling client.loginWithOptions. Any idea how to resolve this warning given the above code?
See https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7052200?hl=en.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cordova, but this otherwise looks good to me. I'm not sure why you would see the warning you're seeing. I'm curious how Google detects this condition. You may want to open a bug in the client SDK repo on GitHub.

Comment: I haven't seen any addt'l warning. I believe all is ok. Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 2):

Do you see a refresh token when you call /.auth/me?  A refresh token must be present in order for the /.auth/refresh API to work correctly.

BTW, you can see the details of these kinds of errors by enabling application logging.  More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log.  Let us know what those details are and we can help figure out how to make the scenario work.

Comment: Thanks Chris, where should I see the 'refresh token' when making the call with /.auth/me? Should this be an object in client.currentUser?

Comment: This might help. Below is my initial login call which successfully logs the user in...
        AzureDbSvc.client.login('google')

        .then(function () {

            var url = AzureDbSvc.client.applicationUrl + '/.auth/me';

            var headers = new Headers();

            headers.append('X-ZUMO-AUTH', AzureDbSvc.client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);

            fetch(url, { headers: headers })

Comment: Here is logging info:
Received request: GET https://name.azurewebsites.net/.auth/refresh
JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:###', Issuer: 'https://name.azurewebsites.net/'.
Warning, The refresh request issued by sid:### (SID: ###) failed because no refresh tokens were found in the token store.
Information Sending response: 403.80 Forbidden